# How do I know if a current source supplies or receive energy?

Tags: power, current, energy, source

In example, I have this circuit:

[image]

I know that in a current source if the polarty is \$-\rightarrow +\$ it supplies energy to the circuit, but how I can determinate the polarity in this case (of 
\$I_{f}\$)?

Comment: it's unsatisfying, but you guess,  and then see if you were right.

Comment: You can't determine the polarity without solving with actual values.

Comment: @vicatcu And how do I know if I guess right? I have calculated the values of voltage and current below

Answer (score 1):

To determine if an element is absorbing or providing power you need to apply the **passive sign convention**, which says that current **enters** the node of an element that is assumed to be at the **higher** voltage. If the product of current and voltage is positive, meaning that both current and voltage are positive or both are negative, then the power is positive. Positive power is power **absorbed**. If the calculated power is negative then the element is **providing** power.

The question that you actually ask in the body of your question was about determining the polarity of the voltage across \$I_f\$. Well, this is a typical circuit analysis problem. Apply KVL, KCL, and Ohm's Law as necessary until you have found all of the circuit voltages and current.

Comment: Note that CircuitLab follows the *passive sign convention*. If you put the circuit into CircuitLab, plug actual values into the circuit, add the expression P(I1), then run the DC solver, a positive power is absorbed, a negative power is provided.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the circuit with this values: \$U_{f1}=130 V\$, \$U_{f2}=80 V\$, \$I_{f}=1.3 A\$, \$R_{1}=150 Ω\$, \$R_{2}=60 Ω\$, \$R_{3}=5 Ω\$ (clockwise loop, but I used the orientation of the current source for the calcs, so the polarity of \$I_{f}\$ is: \$-\rightarrow +\$) and it gives me this: \$I_{Uf1}=-0.133... A\$, \$I_{Uf2}=1.66... A\$, \$U_{If}=156.5 V\$, \$P_{Uf1}=130*(-(-0.13))=17.33 W\$, \$P_{Uf2}=80*1.16=93.33 W\$, \$P_{If}=156.5*1.3= 203.5 W\$. That's means \$U_{f1}\$ and \$U_{f2}\$ absorb power because is \$>0\$? And what about \$I_{f}\$? It's  \$>0\$, is absorbing power too?

Comment: @VolatageIsABadWord -  You are good until here: PIf = 156.5 * 1.3 = 203.5 W, current is going into the lower voltage so:  PIf = -156.5 * 1.3 = -203.5 W

Comment: A good way to check your power calculations is to sum the power of all of the circuit elements. If the sum of the power is not zero you have made a mistake. Also, if the power for **any** resistor is negative, you have made a mistake.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson \$P_{Ri}=U_{Ri}*I_{Ri}=R_{i}*I_{Ri}^{2}W\$ then \$P_{R1}=2.66...W\$, \$P_{R2}=81.66...W\$, \$P_{R3}=8.45 W\$, if I sum all \$P_{Ri}\$ and \$P_{Uf1}\$, \$P_{Uf2}\$ (based on my previous results), it gives me approximately \$203.31\$, which is "almost" the same as \$P_{If}\$, so with the law of conservation of energy \$P_{providing}=P_{absorbed}\$, so \$I_{f}\$ is providing? I would like to know if exist some way to know if \$I_{f}\$ is absorbing or providing energy (like happens with tension sources, \$>0\$ is absorbing, \$<0\$ is providing)

Comment: @Mattman944 So it's absorbing power? I'm so confused, sorry.

Comment: @VolatageIsABadWord - Read Elliot's answer carefully. For the current source, the current is flowing into the lower voltage node, so the power is negative. Negative == providing power.

Answer (score 0):

In the circuit you've drawn, there are no numerical values, therefore it's not possible to tell whether If is sourcing or sinking power.

This sort of circuit is most easily solved with superposition, with either numerical or algebraic values.

Set the current source If to zero, or remove it from the circuit altogether. Solve for the voltage sources and R1/2 alone, as we already know R3 doesn't contribute.

Now restore If and set the voltage sources to zero, or replace them with short circuits. Now solve for the Ufs and R1/2/3 alone.

Now add the two solutions together, voltages at nodes add, currents through components add.

Now you know the voltage across If, and can determine whether it's generating or absorbing power.